# WebAPI multiple routing group for different controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I want different controllers to be accessed from different route:

```
/api1/{Controller}   //for controllers Group 1
/api2/{Controller}   //for controllers Group 2
```

Well I understand it is possible to use attribute routing, or http handler

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api1/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
                handler: // Create controller from group 1
            );
```

I would like to know a better way to do that.

Situation: I have a separate assembly with some WebAPI controllers, I want them to be accessed other than the default /api/XXXXX, when used in the host project.

Answer (score 0):

Do [Attribute Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) and mark your controllers with the route prefix that you want:

```
    [Route("api1")]
    public class FirstController: Controller {...}

    [Route("api2")]
    public class SecondController: Controller {...}
```